# How do I write an interface or abstract class that specifies creation logic?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface, abstract-class

I have a generic class that deals with widgets that can be deserialized from strings. Instances of the generic class will take the type of one of these widgets as a template parameter, and then create these widgets from strings. I wish to use the covariance properties of C#'s generics to write code like `WidgetUser<IWidget>` to deal with objects that may be `WidgetUser<RedWidget>` or `WidgetUser<BlueWidget>`. The problem is that to create a widget from a string inside of `WidgetUser<T>`, I'm forced to add `new()` as a guard. This makes `WidgetUser<IWidget>` an invalid type. Currently, I have code like this:

```
interface IWidget
{
    // Makes this widget into a copy of the serializedWidget
    void Deserialize(string serializedWidget);
}
class WidgetUser<T> where T : IWidget, new()
{
    public void MakeAndUse(string serializedWidget)
    {
        var widget = new T();
        widget.Deserialize(serializedWidget);
        Use(widget);
    }
}
```

With this code, I can make `WidgetUser<BlueWidget>` just fine, because `BigWidget` satisfies `new()`. I cannot write `WidgetUser<IWidget>` because instances of `IWidget` (or an equivalent abstract class) are not guaranteed to work with `new()`. A workaround could be this:

```
abstract class WidgetUser
{
    public abstract void MakeAndUse();
}

class WidgetUser<T> : WidgetUser
    where T : IWidget, new() 
{ 
    /* same as before but with an 'override' on MakeAndUse */ 
}
```

With this code, I can create a `WidgetUser<BlueWidget>` then write code that deals with just `WidgetUser`. I could have similar code with an abstract class `BaseWidget` instead of `IWidget` that accomplishes almost the same thing. This is functional, but I suspect there is a more direct approach that doesn't force me to define a dummy class. How can I convey my intent to the type system without creating dummy classes or extra factories. I just want an interface that says "you can make one of these from a string".

TL;DR:
Is there some way to write an interface or abstract class that lets me create an instance from a string but doesn't require me to have `new()` as a guard on `WidgetUser<T>`?

Comment: `because instances of IWidget are not guaranteed to work with new()` why?  Is it because `new()` must have a public parameterless constructor?  If so then use `class` instead for your [Constraints on Type Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: You will either need to provide, somehow, a factory object, or you need to use the `new()` constraint. Why can't you simply turn your problem around and say that widget classes *must* have a parameterless constructor to work with your widget user?

Comment: How do I specify an interface or abstract base class for widgets that guarantees a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Currently I don't understand what the problem is with your abstract `MakeAndUse` so I have no idea.

Comment: `because instances of IWidget are not guaranteed to work with new()` why?

Comment: The abstract `MakeAndUse` works, but the core of my question is about how to write an interface or abstract class that conveys creation logic. If I had such a technique, the abstract `MakeAndUse` and its abstract class would be unnessesary.

Comment: I can personally only implement `IWidget` on classes with a parameterless constructor, but there is no way to convince the c# type system that `WidgetUser<IWidget>` is guarenteed to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your `Deserialize()` method should be a static method. Therefore it should not be a member of `IWidget` itself - it should be a member of a factory interface, or it should be a static member of a concrete Widget class which is called from a concrete factory method. I show the latter approach below.

(Alternatively, you could use a `Func<IWidget>` delegate to specify it, but it's more usual to provide a full factory interface.)

So I suggest you create the factory interface:

```
interface IWidgetFactory
{
    IWidget Create(string serialisedWidget);
}
```

Then remove the `Deserialize()` from `IWidget`:

```
interface IWidget
{
    // .. Whatever
}
```

Then add a static `Deserialize()` method to each concrete implementation of `IWidget`:

```
class MyWidget: IWidget
{
    public static MyWidget Deserialize(string serializedWidget)
    {
        // .. Whatever you need to deserialise into myDeserializedObject
        return myDeserializedObject;
    }

    // ... Any needed IWidget-implementing methods and properties.
}
```

Then implement the factory for your concrete widget class using the static `Deserialize()` method from the concrete widget class:

```
sealed class MyWidgetFactory : IWidgetFactory
{
    public IWidget Create(string serialisedWidget)
    {
        return MyWidget.Deserialize(serialisedWidget);
    }
}
```

Then add a constructor to your `WidgetUser` class which accepts an `IWidgetFactory` and use it in `MakeAndUse()`:

```
class WidgetUser
{
    public WidgetUser(IWidgetFactory widgetFactory)
    {
        this.widgetFactory = widgetFactory;
    }

    public void MakeAndUse(string serializedWidget)
    {
        var widget = widgetFactory.Create(serializedWidget);
        Use(widget);
    }

    private readonly IWidgetFactory widgetFactory;
}
```

Note that in this scenario, you no longer need the type argument for `WidgetUser`, so I have removed it.

Then when you create the `WidgetUser` you must supply a factory:

```
var widgetUser = new WidgetUser(new MyWidgetFactory());

...

widgetUser.MakeAndUse("MySerializedWidget1");
widgetUser.MakeAndUse("MySerializedWidget2");
```

Passing in a factory allows a lot more flexibility.

For example, imagine that your serialization scheme included a way of telling from the serialized string which kind of widget it is. For the purposes of simplicity, assume that it starts with `"[MyWidget]"` if it's a `MyWidget` and starts with `["MyOtherWidget"]` if it's a `MyOtherWidget`.

Then you could implement a factory that works as a "virtual constructor" that can create any kind of Widget given a serialization string as follows:

```
sealed class GeneralWidgetFactory: IWidgetFactory
{
    public IWidget Create(string serialisedWidget)
    {
        if (serialisedWidget.StartsWith("[MyWidget]"))
            return myWidgetFactory.Create(serialisedWidget);
        else if (serialisedWidget.StartsWith("[MyOtherWidget]"))
            return myOtherWidgetFactory.Create(serialisedWidget);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't know how to deserialize a widget from: " + serialisedWidget);

    }

    readonly MyWidgetFactory      myWidgetFactory      = new MyWidgetFactory();
    readonly MyOtherWidgetFactory myOtherWidgetFactory = new MyOtherWidgetFactory();
}
```

Note that this is generally not the best way to do things - you are better using a Dependency Container such as Autofac to manage this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement `WidgetFactory` and call `WidgetFactory.Create<T>(serializedWidget)` to avoid the usage of `new T()`